# How to calculate rectangle size for specific corner radius?

Tags: geometry

I have some square board .
I would like it to be inside a rounded corners square box.
Question seems to be basic, but how do you calculate how much length you have to add to your square board ,in order to make a rounded square box with specific radius that cover it exactly ?

For example i have a square `30x30mm` board , and i would like to cover it with a square box that has corner radius of `6mm` , how much length do i have to add to the `30mm` , to create that box so it can filled with the original board ( so the board can exactly "live" inside that box )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  It seems to be about carpentry, it might be on topic at http://woodworking.stackexchange.com, but I haven't ever used that site, read it's help material carefully before re-posting there.

Comment: ok sorry for this. thanks .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that the OP application may be carpentry but it seems like an interesting enough geometry problem that it could have programming/graphics applications. Here's what I come up with:

```
Let I = inner square side length (30mm)
    O = outer rounded square side length
    r = corner radius (6mm)

Decompose the outer rounded square into 9 sections:
    1 center square (with diagonal length d and side length c)
    4 side squares (left, right, above, and below)
    4 round corners

Since the inner square fits into the outer square,
the outer rounded square diagonal is I * sqrt(2)

Since there are 2 rounded corners the diagonal of the center square is
    d = I sqrt(2) - 2 * r

The diagonal of the center square is sqrt(2) times its side
    d = c * sqrt(2)

Equating these two
    c = I - r * sqrt(2)

The side length of the outer square is
    O = c + 2 * r

Substituting for c
    O = I + r * (2 - sqrt(2))
```

Your question asked for the amount of length to add which would be

```
length to add = O - I = r * (2 - sqrt(2))
```

In your case, 6mm * (2 - sqrt(2)) = **3.515mm** (approximately)